# Variável zerada em javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

```
//Nosso time
var nomeTime = prompt("Qual o nome do seu time ?");
var vitorias = parseInt(prompt("Quantas vitórias seu time teve ?"));
var empates = parseInt(prompt("Quantos empates seu time teve ?"));
var derrotas = parseInt(prompt("Quantas derrotas seu time teve ?"));
var totalJogos = 0;
var totalPontos = 0;
//Oponente
var nomeTimeO = prompt("Qual o nome do time Oponente?");
var vitoriasO = parseInt(prompt("Quantas vitórias ele teve ?"));
var empatesO = parseInt(prompt("Quantos empates ele teve ?"));
var derrotasO = parseInt(prompt("Quantas derrotas ele teve ?"));
var totalJogosO = 0;
var totalPontosO = 0;
//Funções
    //Calcula jogos
function calculaJogos(vitorias, empates, derrotas, vitoriasO, empatesO, derrotasO){
    totalJogos = vitorias + empates + derrotas;
    totalJogosO = vitoriasO + empatesO + derrotasO;
    return totalJogos;
    return totalJogosO;
};
    //Calcula pontos
function calculaPontos(vitorias, derrotas, empates, vitoriasO, derrotasO, empatesO){
    var pVitorias = vitorias * 3;
    var pVitoriasO = vitoriasO * 3;
    totalPontos = pVitorias + empates - derrotas;
    totalPontosO = pVitoriasO + empatesO - derrotasO;
    return totalPontos;
    return totalPontosO;

};
//Call functions
calculaJogos(vitorias, empates, derrotas, vitoriasO, empatesO, derrotasO);
calculaPontos(vitorias, empates, vitoriasO, empatesO);
//Resultados
document.write("O time <b>" + nomeTimeO + "</b> jogou um total de " + totalJogosO + " jogos, tendo feito " + totalPontosO + " pontos. <br>");
document.write("Vitórias: " + vitoriasO + "<br>Derrotas: " + derrotasO + "<br>Empates: " + empatesO + "<br>");
//Comparações
if(totalPontos < totalPontosO){
    document.write("Seu time está indo <b>pior</b> que " + nomeTimeO);
}else if(totalPontos > totalPontosO){
    document.write("Seu time está indo <b>melhor</b> que " + nomeTimeO);
}else if(totalPontos == totalPontosO){
    document.write("Seu time está <b>empatado</b> com " + nomeTimeO);
};
```

Dado o código acima, queria entender o porque de:

- se o último for apenas um simples else, mesmo estando acima ou abaixo do numero, aparece o mesmo aviso de empate
- o valor de pontos do oponente "totalPontosO", está e fica zerado, porém, os meus pontos funcionam perfeitamente.

Comment: A Sua segunda pergunta é impossível de responder se você não informar  quais são os dados que estão sendo utilizados. Outra coisa, uma derrota realmente conta um ponto a menos?

Comment: Vc tem 2 return na mesma função, isso não existe. Quando você dá return a função acaba, nada abaixo é executado, você precisa retornar um objeto ou array com os dois resultados, ou chamar a função duas vezes com parâmetros diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primariamente:
Uma função só passa por um e somente um return (mas os returns na sua função são inúteis pois você ja alterou as variável do escopo global antes do return)

Agora, para o seu problema de NaN:
Você definiu a function calculaPontos recebendo 6 parâmetros, mas você só esta passando 4 parâmetros para ela:

```
calculaPontos(vitorias, empates, vitoriasO, empatesO);
```

Talvez você tenha duvidas de como funciona uma function, então vou explicar:
A function vai receber os parâmetros de acordo com a posição na qual eles foram definidos na function e não de acordo com o nome.

```
var some = function (a, b) { return a + b }
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
some(x, y);
```

Nesse caso a variável a da function esta recebendo o valor da variável x global e a variável b da function esta recebendo a variável y global.
Quando voce nao passa todos os parâmetros da funtion, as variáveis que não recebem valor ficam com o valor undefined.

No seu caso, como você não passou todos os valores você esta tentando fazer uma operação matemática de um numero com dois undefineds, qualquer numero com operação matemática com um undefined resulta em um NaN (Not a Number).

Answer (score 1):

Algumas coisas sobre o seu código:

1) Caso você use apenas else no final, ele só será executado caso haja uma igualdade, visto que você está testando por menor e maior, o único resultado diferente disso seria igualdade, então um else no final é apropriado.

2) Vc tem 2 return na mesma função, isso não existe. Quando você dá return a função acaba, nada abaixo é executado, você precisa retornar um objeto ou array com os dois resultados, ou chamar a função duas vezes com parâmetros diferentes.

```
 function calculaPontos(vitorias, derrotas, empates, vitoriasO, derrotasO, empatesO){
    var pVitorias = vitorias * 3;
    var pVitoriasO = vitoriasO * 3;

    totalPontos = pVitorias + empates - derrotas;
    totalPontosO = pVitoriasO + empatesO - derrotasO;

    var resultado = [totalPontos, totalPontosO];
    return resultado;
};
```

Uma ideia de como resolver seu problema, utilizando um array com o resultado da função.

Comment: usei o else, mas como explicado, mesmo estando maior ou menor, o mesmo continuava aparecendo